# Action Potential

Tags: physiology, neurophysiology, action-potential

I was wondering what exactly initiates an action potential? I understand that for depolarisation to occur, the membrane potential must first pass through the threshold potential, but what process leads to the membrane potential being raised to the threshold potential in the first place? I suppose this question would pertain more so to nerve cells since in muscle cells the membrane potential is raised due to the opening of nicotinic receptors and the influx of cations.

Comment: In addition to the duplicate which answers your question, I would note that a typical textbook progression introducing neuroscience is to go from resting membrane potential to excitable membranes (= action potentials) to synaptic transmission, so if you're learning from a textbook you may just need to keep going to the next chapter.